# BTRFS "ghost" directories/files are not deleted

Tags: btrfs

I get an "not empty" error when I try to delete a directory with `sudo rm -fr /net7.0`.
The directory:

```
➜ ls -la net7.0
ls: cannot access 'x86': There is no such file or directory
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 qmater qmater 12 июл 15 20:37 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 qmater qmater 12 июл 15 19:28 ..
d????????? ? ?      ?       ?            ? x86
...
d????????? ? ?      ?       ?            ? x86
```

Unsuccessful attempts:

```
➜ sudo btrfs check --repair --force /dev/sda3  
enabling repair mode
Opening filesystem to check...
WARNING: filesystem mounted, continuing because of --force
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda3
UUID: 6305e712-5f4b-41af-adee-6b0780e79cae
repair mode will force to clear out log tree, are you sure? [y/N]: y
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=751315435520 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=751315435520 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=751315435520 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=751315435520 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=750319124480 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=750319124480 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=750319124480 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
parent transid verify failed on 751315664896 wanted 6609 found 6611
parent transid verify failed on 751315664896 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 751315451904 wanted 6609 found 6611
Ignoring transid failure
ERROR: child eb corrupted: parent bytenr=750319124480 item=277 parent level=1 child level=1
leaf parent key incorrect 750319108096
btrfs unable to find ref byte nr 751314223104 parent 0 root 2  owner 2 offset 0
path->slots[0]: 0 path->nodes[0]:
leaf 750319108096 items 171 free space 1960 generation 6610 owner EXTENT_TREE
leaf 750319108096 flags 0x0(��fU) backref revision 1
fs uuid 6305e712-5f4b-41af-adee-6b0780e79cae
chunk uuid 4691bb50-3e60-485e-aff3-d7deed1fc968
    item 0 key (42354 DIR_INDEX 19228) itemoff 16235 itemsize 48
        location key (449174 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
        transid 6594 data_len 0 name_len 18
        name: 87f3212a88db4452_0
...
    item 140 key (42354 DIR_INDEX 19461) itemoff 9515 itemsize 48
        location key (449595 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
        transid 6611 data_len 0 name_len 18
        name: 982250d99cd6c31b_0
    item 141 key (42355 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 9355 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 6437 size 24 nbytes 24
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 5 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1689425559.108589734 (2023-07-15 19:52:39)
        ctime 1684932607.900679600 (2023-05-24 19:50:07)
        mtime 1680182865.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:45)
        otime 1680239263.90155114 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 142 key (42355 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 9340 itemsize 15
        index 2 namelen 5 name: index
    item 143 key (42355 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 9136 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 144 key (42355 EXTENT_DATA 0) itemoff 9091 itemsize 45
        generation 446 type 0 (inline)
        inline extent data size 24 ram_bytes 24 compression 0 (none)
    item 145 key (42356 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 8931 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 6611 size 28 nbytes 0
        block group 0 mode 40700 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 1446 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1680234975.0 (2023-03-31 10:56:15)
        ctime 1689430594.802952099 (2023-07-15 21:16:34)
        mtime 1689430594.802952099 (2023-07-15 21:16:34)
        otime 1680239263.90155114 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 146 key (42356 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 8912 itemsize 19
        index 3 namelen 9 name: index-dir
    item 147 key (42356 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 8708 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 148 key (42356 DIR_ITEM 2837238542) itemoff 8664 itemsize 44
        location key (449593 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
        transid 6611 data_len 0 name_len 14
        name: the-real-index
    item 149 key (42356 DIR_INDEX 189) itemoff 8620 itemsize 44
        location key (449593 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
        transid 6611 data_len 0 name_len 14
        name: the-real-index
    item 150 key (42358 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 8460 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 5899 size 57541 nbytes 61440
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 5 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1680182865.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:45)
        ctime 1684932607.900679600 (2023-05-24 19:50:07)
        mtime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        otime 1680239263.94155408 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 151 key (42358 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 8432 itemsize 28
        index 4 namelen 18 name: b86bf06e67bc2413_0
    item 152 key (42358 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 8228 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 153 key (42358 EXTENT_DATA 0) itemoff 8175 itemsize 53
        generation 446 type 1 (regular)
        extent data disk byte 463805399040 nr 61440
        extent data offset 0 nr 61440 ram 61440
        extent compression 0 (none)
    item 154 key (42359 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 8015 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 6446 size 26139 nbytes 28672
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 52 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1689425560.56589707 (2023-07-15 19:52:40)
        ctime 1689425808.967308883 (2023-07-15 19:56:48)
        mtime 1689425808.967308883 (2023-07-15 19:56:48)
        otime 1680239263.94155408 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 155 key (42359 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 7987 itemsize 28
        index 5 namelen 18 name: b548d086f83d719e_0
    item 156 key (42359 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 7783 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 157 key (42359 EXTENT_DATA 0) itemoff 7730 itemsize 53
        generation 6446 type 1 (regular)
        extent data disk byte 498101583872 nr 28672
        extent data offset 0 nr 28672 ram 28672
        extent compression 0 (none)
    item 158 key (42360 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 7570 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 5899 size 25230 nbytes 28672
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 5 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1680182866.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:46)
        ctime 1684932607.900679600 (2023-05-24 19:50:07)
        mtime 1680182866.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:46)
        otime 1680239263.94155408 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 159 key (42360 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 7542 itemsize 28
        index 6 namelen 18 name: 6c56f1c5c77f6779_0
    item 160 key (42360 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 7338 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 161 key (42360 EXTENT_DATA 0) itemoff 7285 itemsize 53
        generation 446 type 1 (regular)
        extent data disk byte 463804514304 nr 28672
        extent data offset 0 nr 28672 ram 28672
        extent compression 0 (none)
    item 162 key (42362 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 7125 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 5899 size 16945 nbytes 20480
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 5 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        ctime 1684932607.900679600 (2023-05-24 19:50:07)
        mtime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        otime 1680239263.94155408 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 163 key (42362 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 7097 itemsize 28
        index 8 namelen 18 name: 89236a4167e66d6d_0
    item 164 key (42362 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 6893 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 165 key (42362 EXTENT_DATA 0) itemoff 6840 itemsize 53
        generation 446 type 1 (regular)
        extent data disk byte 463804018688 nr 20480
        extent data offset 0 nr 20480 ram 20480
        extent compression 0 (none)
    item 166 key (42366 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 6680 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 5899 size 13447 nbytes 16384
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 5 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        ctime 1684932607.900679600 (2023-05-24 19:50:07)
        mtime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        otime 1680239263.98155701 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
    item 167 key (42366 INODE_REF 42354) itemoff 6652 itemsize 28
        index 12 namelen 18 name: c8b578a9d2c3f4bf_0
    item 168 key (42366 XATTR_ITEM 1167204678) itemoff 6448 itemsize 204
        location key (0 UNKNOWN.0 0) type XATTR
        transid 5899 data_len 160 name_len 14
        name: security.NTACL
        data 
    item 169 key (42366 EXTENT_DATA 0) itemoff 6395 itemsize 53
        generation 446 type 1 (regular)
        extent data disk byte 463801925632 nr 16384
        extent data offset 0 nr 16384 ram 16384
        extent compression 0 (none)
    item 170 key (42367 INODE_ITEM 0) itemoff 6235 itemsize 160
        generation 446 transid 5899 size 8185 nbytes 8192
        block group 0 mode 100600 links 1 uid 1000 gid 1000 rdev 0
        sequence 5 flags 0x0(none)
        atime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        ctime 1684932607.900679600 (2023-05-24 19:50:07)
        mtime 1680182867.0 (2023-03-30 20:27:47)
        otime 1680239263.98155701 (2023-03-31 12:07:43)
ERROR: failed to zero log tree: -5
ERROR: attempt to start transaction over already running one
extent buffer leak: start 750319124480 len 16384
WARNING: dirty eb leak (aborted trans): start 750319124480 len 16384
extent buffer leak: start 750319140864 len 16384
WARNING: dirty eb leak (aborted trans): start 750319140864 len 16384
extent buffer leak: start 750319108096 len 16384
WARNING: dirty eb leak (aborted trans): start 750319108096 len 16384
```